# Print Debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, plugins, printing, crash

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to compile and debug a plugin for an application that runs under Windows.
The plugin has some problem and it crashes. I have been running VS in Debug mode but when the application crashes VS stack trace has nothing from my code. It is possibly the application itself that crashes. So I though I could try to figure out which part of my code does something the host application doesn't like by sprinkling a few print statements here and there in my code. That generally works as expected on *nix systems but in Windows I can't find where the output of those print goes. Can anybody point me in the right direction?
Also, if using prints do debug is too 1970's and somebody knows a better way to figure out where too look when the stack trace doesn't reveal anything interesting please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If i know correctly, debug.print is only executed when a debugger is attached, otherwise it is lost. (this applies to c# and vb.net).
You can use a logger to log your problems to some database or text file. A like NLOG to do the simple "log to a txt file" job. Additionally, you do not need to remove your logging code when shipping your addon -simply supress logmessages with low debug level.
Also, you could log to the windows event log, but is cluttered ny boatloads of junk, so you might have a hard time to differentiate that output.
Eventlog: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301279